# SigningCredentials on .NET Core 1.0

Tags: cryptography, claims-based-identity, .net-core, encryption-symmetric, powerbi-embedded

SigningCredentials on .NET Core is different from .NET 4.0

Comment: Are you sure you have to hash the key first? Do both JWTs verify using the same key in jwt.io?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent code in .NET Core would be:

```
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accessKey);
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
```

The class names have changed a little, but everything should work the same. Make sure you are using the latest package versions.

Comment: @ChrisWu That should be a separate question, IMHO.

Comment: @ChrisWu No problem! I was feeling confused, because it really looked like the key was being hashed twice in your code. I was about to build a side-by-side sample, and then you commented. :) Glad you got it working! Upvotes are always appreciated ;)

Comment: I was starting feeling cold about .NET Core, now this seems added a little confidence about it.